# Menu moves when hovered over

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

I've created a rollover image menu in Dreamweaver. The days of the week are images. So is the rollover image that appears on hover. My problem is when you hover over the days of the week, the hover image pushes the text down.

I've mocked together two screen grabs showing the menu before and during it's hover (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/FbPmx6mez/hover-example.png)

I read about z-indexes and tried making the menu have a greater number than the hover but that hasn't worked, nor did it help making the position fixed. In the end this is the only CSS I have styling the menu -

== CSS ==

```
 #nav {
text-align:center;
list-style: none;


}
#nav ul
{
list-style-type:none;

}
#nav li
{
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
```

}

[Here is the JSfiddle with the full javascript, html and css](http://jsfiddle.net/r2FF7/6/) I've shown just one category for ease.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Try using `vertical-align: top` on the containing `div` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp Also, your jsfiddle has no hover effect.

Comment: Why are you using images for this??

Answer (score 0):

Using `Javacript` is overkill for what you're trying to accomplish, just use a sprite image, and manage the rest via `CSS`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvdc6/)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { float:left}
ul li { float:left; list-style:none; }
ul a { display:block; text-indent:-9999em; }

ul li.home { width:100px; height:50px; }
ul li.home a { background:url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat 0 0 }

ul li.home a:hover { background-position:0 -50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/r2FF7/18/

```
#nav li a img{
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Full page on: http://jsfiddle.net/r2FF7/18/show/

Comment: I tried this but the images still move. I want the days of the week to stay fixed

Comment: What do you mean? You want other non-hover images change their size to be smaller when a image is being hover?

Comment: I want the days of the week to stay fixed and dont move when they are hovered. At the moment when you hover a day the hover image pushes the day down. I want the day to stay put

Comment: Yeah.. i've mocked up an image to illustrate what I mean - http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/LyCmx6w68/hover-example2.png So the days stay fixed when hovered

Comment: Ah-ha! So, #nav li a img{
    vertical-align:top;
}
is added? Brilliant. Thank you for being patient with me